# Marshal byte to enum

Tags: c++, vb.net, enums, marshalling

So i'm parsing an unmanaged structure to a managed structure with the use of the Marshal class. So far everything works as expected except for the fact that i'm struggling how to convert a unmanaged Char to a Managed enum type.

For example:

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
Public Structure UnamangedToManaged
     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)>
     Public _Enum As ManagedCustomEnum
end structure


Public Enum ManagedCustomEnum
    Value_1
    Value_2
    Value_3
    Value_4
    Value_etc
End Enum
```

This gives the error: `Unvalid combination`

If i just simply remove the `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)>` then the parsing works except the index for the rest of the structure is off, giving unvalid values.

Tried a lot of possibilities and also read all the MSDN articles, however still no luck.

Hopefully someone could simply point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `Enum` has a default underlying type of `Int32`. You have to change that to `Byte` in your declaration:

```vb
Public Enum ManagedCustomEnum As Byte
    Value_1
    Value_2
    Value_3
    Value_4
    Value_etc
End Enum
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, sometimes it's simpler than you think :-)